# Style PHP variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<?php    
...
$name = trim($_POST["username"]);
...
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
"<span style='color:red;'>'.$name.'</span> <br>login now";</script>';

?>
```

Why the style isn't working?
When I erase the style and span the code is working fine.

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? White screen of death?

Comment: "isn't working" meaning it prints(echo) nothing, so my guess is that this code is not valid...

Comment: See: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 2):

Your need to escape the quotes around `'color:red;'`, that's invalid:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
"<span style=\'color:red;\'>'.$name.'</span> <br>login now";</script>'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your need to escape `style=\'color:red;\'`

```
<?php
echo '<div id="message"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
                    "<span style=\'color:red;\'>'.$name.'</span> <br>login now";</script>';
?>
```

Comment: How's this any different than my answer?

Comment: oh , You sent this answer .

Comment: yeah, I guess we both had the same idea :)